# Returning a Subset of Strings from 10000 ascii strings

Tags: java, algorithm, substring

My college is getting over so I have started preparing for the interviews to get the JOB and I came across this interview question while I was preparing for the interview

> 1. You have a set of 10000 ascii strings (loaded from a file)
> 2. A string is input from stdin.
> 3. Write a pseudocode that returns (to stdout) a subset of strings in (1) that contain the same distinct characters (regardless of order) as
>      input in (2). Optimize for time.
> 4. Assume that this function will need to be invoked repeatedly. Initializing the string array once and storing in memory is okay .
>      Please avoid solutions that require looping through all 10000 strings.

Can anyone provide me a general pseudocode/algorithm kind of thing how to solve this problem? I am scratching my head thinking about the solution. I am mostly familiar with Java.

Comment: Well, break it down. What's important here? Which strings contain the same distinct characters as the input string. So the straightforward (though not necessarily best) approach would be to transform each of the 10000 strings into a string that contains only their distinct characters. Then do the same for the input string, and finally find which of the 10000 strings match it. Figuring out such a "transform", as well as how to actually perform the "match" is the fun part. And from there, perhaps you can think of a more inventive, faster solution.

Comment: Construct a data structure that can map distinct characters to a list of strings (Hash table, access is `O(1)`). Once you have that data structure, the rest is trivial.

Comment: Please avoid solutions that require looping through all 10000 strings - sorry to break it to you, but to know which characters are in a string, you have to loop them through at least once. You can optimize for repeated access.

Comment: Yeah question states that we need to avoid solutions that require looping throguh 10000 strings.

Comment: @VincentSavard, Can you provide me step by step alogrithm or pseudocode kind of thing which I can use to write some code on that?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to know if a set is contained within another set without looping 10k times. The @VincentSavard solution is an original approach, but in fact it seems to only scramble the actions: instead of looping and tell if the string passes the test, it first loops to build a map (which increases memory consumption) and then looks at the map to compute the result. I think it will use exactly as many CPU and memory as the dlev solution, only it has a better dress :)

Comment: I am unsure what is meant by "contain the same distinct characters". Does it mean strings which *only* contain those characters? Are repeats of the same character allowed, or just permutations?

Comment: @Raffaele - see Bohemian's answer for an example of how the map would be used: the idea is that on each lookup, you only need to transform the input string and not cycle through all 10,000 (beyond the initial cycle through to pre-compute the map-- that's OK, it's the subsequent iterations you're trying to avoid).

Comment: @NeilCoffey I don't think you can compute the map without iterating through all of the characters in a (possibly adjusted) source string. To me, this is a bad question.

Comment: @NeilCoffey Please don't add `[homework]` tags to posts, as it is [officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: OK sorry, missed that announcement!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an O(1) algorithm!

Initialization:

- For each string, sort characters, removing duplicates - eg "trees" becomes "erst"
- load sorted word into a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) tree using the sorted characters, adding a reference to the original word to the list of words stored at the each node traversed

Search:

- sort input string same as initialization for source strings
- follow source string trie using the characters, at the end node, return all words referenced there

Comment: It's worth adding that you don't necessarily need to SORT the characters if the range of possible values of a character is fairly restricted: you can just count how many of each occur. Your key could then be an object containing those counts, or simply a strong hash of the counts concatenated in order. This kind of issue is partly why I say in another comment that to "optimise for time" you really need more information on what the input data would typically look like.

Comment: @NeilCoffey I disagree It needs to be sorted. see edited answer - I improved (fixed) the algorithm. It rocks now :)

Comment: Ah, OK, if you use a trie rather than a flat hash map, then yes effectively it does. (Potentially, nodes of a trie could be character counts, but at that point I think you may as well use the method I mention with a flat map.)

Comment: I'd like to see this coded and benchmarked, because to me it looks like the *brute force* part is only moved from the straight loop to the `Trie.add()` method. My opinion is once the `Trie` has detected the parent node for the `String`, you already have the solution, so keeping objects around and traverse the tree is a waste of effort. But maybe I don't understand the idea, so I wonder if anybody can code this approach

Comment: @Raffaele actually I'd like to code this for fun. I'll do it a bit later tho - busy right now

Comment: @Bohemian it'd be very interesting :) I put an initial [gist online](https://gist.github.com/4092306). Hope you can find it useful to implement your algorithm

Answer (score 0):

They say optimise for time, so I guess we're safe to abuse space as much as we want.

In that case, you could do an initial pass on the 10000 strings and build a mapping from each of the unique characters present in the 10000 to their index (rather a set of their indices). That way you can ask the mapping the question, which sets contain character 'x'? Call this mapping M> ( order: O(nm) when n is the number of strings and m is their maximum length)

To optimise in time again, you could reduce the stdin input string to unique characters, and put them in a queue, Q. (order O(p), p is the length of the input string)

Start a new disjoint set, say S. Then let S =  Q.extractNextItem.

Now you could loop over the rest of the unique characters and find which sets contain all of them.

While (Q is not empty) (loops O(p)) {

S = S intersect Q.extractNextItem (close to O(1) depending on your implementation of disjoint sets)

}

voila, return S.

Total time: O(mn + p + p*1) = O(mn + p)

(Still early in the morning here, I hope that time analysis was right)

Comment: To really optimise for time, you would need more information about the input data which is not provided. So I wouldn't get too bogged down in this-- they basically want to make sure that the interviewee is able to explore algorithmic options beyond the "brute force" option of looping through all of the strings counting characters.

Comment: Still, they ask to optimise for time, so I think it would be good to provide a time analysis. Just to show that you understand that you're getting something better than worst case brute force.

Answer (score 0):

As Bohemian says, a trie tree is definitely the way to go!

This sounds like the way an address book lookup would work on a phone. Start punching digits in, and then filter the address book based on the number representation as well as any of the three (or actually more if using international chars) letters that number would represent.